# LINQ with list<int> quering the Value of a Dictonary<int, object>

Tags: linq, list, dictionary

I have a problem with a query. I have a List with int and want to use it to get the values from my dictionary. The dictionary-keys are int and some of them have the value of the list-items. My question is how i get the objects out of the dictionary, thats keys matces the list items. Was programming JAVA the last years and now struggling with LINQ :(

Thanks in advance

Problem solved. Thank you all :)
No idea how to close this topic. I am reading stackoverflow since one year, but this was my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to join list items with dictionary KeyValuePair entries on entry key. And then select entry value from each joined pair:

```
var values = from l in list
             join kvp in dictionary on l equals kvp.Key
             select kvp.Value;
```

Lambda syntax:

```
var values = list.Join(dictionary, l => l, kvp => kvp.Key, (l,kvp) => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Seems i have a lot to learn. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @Sardoan what .NET version you are using? Also is it OK with `from`, `join` and `select` keywords?

Comment: I am using 4.5. But as i am still learning and tried the stuff with lamdbas and from join i would like to see the from join solution too. Failed with that one too :(

Comment: @Sardoan make sure you have added Linq namespace with `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

### Basically:

```
var value = dictionary[integerKey];
```

Or:

```
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(integerKey, out value)) {

}
```

### You can also create an extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> FilterValuesBy<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEnumerable<TKey> filter)
    {
        if (dictionary == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        if (filter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filter");
        var coll = filter as ICollection<TKey> ?? new HashSet<TKey>(filter);

        return dictionary.Where(kvp => coll.Contains(kvp.Key)).Select(kvp => kvp.Value); 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToDictionary(x => x);
        var filter = Enumerable.Range(0, 2);

        foreach (var i in dict.FilterValuesBy(filter))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

### Simple Linq method chain:

```
        var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToDictionary(x => x);
        var filter = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).ToList();

        var filtered = dict.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: My problem was the for each. I started every time a requst to my businesslayer witch used the repository to get a result. This way i got a sql-server crash after 7gb memory-use. I am rewriting my export modul now wich exports the hole database and uses rdlc to create pdfs. I really need to get better in linq. Would be no problem to write the stuff in sql, but using EF i need to use LINQ. Thanks for the help :)